# Javascript return function meaning

Tags: javascript, return

I understand `return` basically terminates a function. But somehow in this case, I'm not sure which return is actually finishing up a function.

```
var THRESHOLD = 12;
var v = [5, 2, 16, 4, 3, 18, 20];
var res;

res = v.some(function(element, index, array) {
  console.log('element:', element);
  if (element >= THRESHOLD) {
    return true; //#1
  }

  return false; // #2
});
console.log('res:', res);
```

Say it's iterating at v[0]=5, it skips if(){} and go ahead to `return false //2`, 
Why is that after #2 return, the function still keep looping?

Comment: sorry about multiple editting, it was really confusing expresion

Comment: oh sorry my bad.. i confused every with some.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function does not keep running. It is being called several times because you are iterating over the array

Comment: but doesn't the return false stop the iteration?

Comment: @XiaoQu No, otherwise how could it find your `true` value? [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Description): *some() executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value*. Returning `true` will stop the iteration though

Answer (score 0):

that happends because the 1st element is less than 10 and that 1st return false kill the loop.